# Javafx Adding Rectangle Object

Tags: java, object, javafx

This is my `Brick` object

```
public class Brick {

    public Brick() {
        Rectangle brick = new Rectangle(50, 20, 50, 20);
        brick.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
    }
}
```

How can I add this to the in my scene by using `JavaFx`?
I don't want to create a rectangle in my main class because I'll create a rectangle array.

Comment: *"I don't want to create a rectangle in my main class because I'll create a rectangle array."* I don't think creating a rectangle and creating a rectangle array are mutually exclusive. This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe, what exactly would be wrong with using an array and initializing it in a loop. Given the code you posted the `Brick` class shouldn't be class in it's own right... Or at least it should be a utility class...

Comment: i want create a rectangle class like this public class Brick {

     public Brick (int x, int y) {
         Rectangle brick = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 20);
         brick.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
     }
}

Comment: Why not `static Rectangle createBrick(double x, double y) { ... return brick; }` ?

Comment: then i'll make a loop in my main class and line up them by using loop then show it in the scene. How can i do that ? Can you fill me in?

Comment: how can i show the bricks in the scene or whatever after i create them?

Comment: By adding them to the scene graph (using a appropriate layout as container). If you don't know how to do that yet, it may be best to start with a tutorial...

Comment: i've done it thanks for the createBrick opinion :)